# Can I use the same PVC for multiple Pods with OpenEBS?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs

I am using openebs 0.6 in kubernertes 10.5 and want to map one pvc with two different pods on different nodes. but it is failing. I came across this link by doing google https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67142 
Can OpenEBS supports this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use same PVC for multiple Pods in OpenEBS, as OpenEBS volumes are exposed via block storage using iSCSI. Please visit the link below for more info. https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/faq.html#can-i-use-the-same-pvc-for-multiple-pods